# Lift. MappedText vs MappedTextarea?

Tags: scala, orm, lift

According to sources they differ in that `MappedText` is not mixed with `StringValidators` and `HasApplyBoxString` (though it's method `apply(ov: Box[String])` has been deprecated). Also `MappedText` seems to be unlimitted (at least at the Lift/Scala layer) in length.

Whar are the usage guides on using these two similar (at first glance) classes?

Answer (score 1):

One will be rendered as an input type="text" tag and the other as a textarea tag in the html output.